# Cant set Start State of robot in planning pane

Tags: ros, motion-planning, rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I generated my robots moveit package with moveit_setup_assistant, but i cant set start state in planing pane in rviz. I just can set goal state, and when i click "Plan" button, it moves between "unknown" start state and goal state in infinite loop.

I have no idea what can be wrong.

Thank you for any help.

Thank You, gvdhoorn. It helped. But i have one more  question, that i forgot to write above:

There  is no reaction when i move effectors ball in rviz. I looked for right option in "Planning Request" this time, but didnt find anything about this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214186/cant-set-start-state-of-robot-in-planning-pane/) by [tambel](https://answers.ros.org/users/22448/tambel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-21**:
Please explain what you mean with "there is no reaction". If you mean that the visualised robot does not seem to follow the interactive marker, then it could be an issue with your kinematics / planning group setup. Without more details about your particular pkg, we cannot tell you very much.

**Comment by [mizu_lily](https://answers.ros.org/users/26610/mizu_lily/) on 2016-06-17**:
I have the same problem. I have a three-link planar which can only move on a plane. After setting up MoveIt pkg, I can't update the start state to current state. That means the trajectory it plans is always from all zeros and the robot moves back first then follows trajectory in every execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could it be that the visualisation of the start state is not enabled? It's under *MotionPlanning - Planning Request* , then *Query Start State*. Make sure the checkbox is checked.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1